# Weird effect when calling an hoisting function in javascript

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I am very newbie in JavaScript. I learned Hoisting behavior in JS and i tested it by myself with a simple program example.

My program generate an Array which contains random numbers then call `unique()` who deletes all duplicates elements inside the Array :

```
const NUMBERS = [34, 25, 45, 11, 36, 98, 58, 97, 56]
const ARRAY_LENGTH = 4;
  
function getRandomNumberList () {
  let res = []
  for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
    res.push(NUMBERS[Math.floor(Math.random() * ARRAY_LENGTH)])
  }
  return res
}


// Generate array with random numbers 
let randomArray = getRandomNumberList() 

// When we compute this, First call doesn't Work
// the console.log return [ 34, 45, 34, 34 ]
console.log(randomArray)

// First call with Hoisting
// Because of console log, return [ 34, 45, 25 ] instead of [ 34, 45 ]
unique(randomArray)    

// This function remove duplicates entries if exist.  
function unique (arr) {
   let uniqueArray = [...new Set(arr)]  
   return uniqueArray 
};

// Second call without hoisting. This seems to work all the time
// return [ 34, 45 ]
unique(randomArray)
```

However, I was confronted to a weird behavior.

The First call doesn't work when I call `console.log` **above** the first call. However if I remove the console.log(), it's seems to work.

Can anyone pls explain me why this behavior occurred ?

**Note that** I used **RunJS** scratchpad to run my program.

Comment: Please post your code here as text, not images.

Comment: Not sure why you remove the snippet I added to your question using your  code to actually run it  here.  If you wish, please add that yourself, making it easier for others to answer with examples (hint, hit CTRL-M when editing

Comment: Why is `[ 11, 34, 45 ]` wrong?

Comment: I believe this to be a bug with RunJS scratchpad, but I can't be sure. This code works fine in Node.js, but does not work when I use it in repl.it.
If you assign the result of `unique(randomArray)` it works fine.